# Reset state after doing something without re-rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanna to highlight a new task after it is created. However, the whole table will re-render when a new task is added, so even though I have so many occasions to do something before rendering, it will be reset. So I declare a `newTaskID: null` state intended store the id and highlight it after rendering which is good. However, I also need to set `newTaskID: null` back to null which again cause a re-render which will reset my table and my highlighted task. I know I miss something but cannot understand it yet. Please help.

```js
constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
        newTaskID: null
    }
}

createTask = (value) => {
    /.....
    this.setState({ newTaskID: value.id })
}

componentDidMount() {
    gantt.attachEvent('onGanttRender', function () {
        if (this.state.newTaskID) {
            //Highlight task and set state back to null
            highlightTask(this.state.newTaskID)
            //Set state back to null so it won't highlight anything
            this.setState({ newTaskID: null })
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an additional flag to the state to check if there is an highlighted task. It would be something like this:

```
this.state = {
  newTaskID: null,
  taskIsHighlighted: false,
}
```

And you should set `taskIsHighlighted` to true when task was highlighted and set to false in the next render. Your `componentDidMount` will be:

```
componentDidMount() {
    gantt.attachEvent('onGanttRender', function () {
        if (this.state.newTaskID) {
            //Highlight task and set state back to null
            highlightTask(this.state.newTaskID)
            //Set state back to null so it won't highlight anything
            this.setState({ taskIsHighlighted: true })
        }

        if (this.state.taskIsHighlighted) {
          this.setState({ newTaskID: null, taskIsHighlighted: false })
        }
    })
}
```